# autocomplete json

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete, razor, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i have follow the following wave for **`autocomplete`** and  **`datepicker`**  but the auto complete can't work Secondly is there any **`razor syntax`** to show the datepicker and autocomplete

**javascriptfile**

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete") });
    });
    $(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker();    
})
```

**The View File**

```
    @model TestDateTimePicker.Models.TestClass

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>TestClass</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "City","City")" class="text-box single-line" id="City" name="City" type="text" value="" />                        
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">            
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="Date" name="Date" type="text" value="" data-datepicker="true"/>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)            
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>



  }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**The Json Controller**

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(String s)
        {
            var d = db.Cities
                .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(s))
                .Select(r => new { label = r.Name });            
            return Json(d, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors? Can you request the AutoComplete action directly in your browser? Does it return valid JSON?

Comment: nothing is display as autocomplete

Comment: how to verify that JSON is valid

Comment: So maybe the JSON result is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "City", "City")
```

should be

```
@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "City")
```

The third argument that you are using represents route values which must be an anonymous object and not a string. As far as the autocomplete plugin is concerned, it uses the `term` query string when performing the AJAX request to fetch the data. So you will have to rename your controller action parameter as well:

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term)
{
    var d = db.Cities
              .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(term))
              .Select(r => new { label = r.Name });            
    return Json(d, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Also make sure that that `jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js` script is referenced in your page (cannot see it in your code example).

If it still doesn't work make sure that the AutoComplete action doesn't throw an exception when performing the query. Also look with FireBug or Developer Tools if there aren't some javascript errors and if the AJAX request is correctly sent.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this solution is: We need to use item.label name because the AJAX will return the value in list format so we need to extract the value as shown in the below example.

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Ajax</title>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script>
                 $(function() { 
                    $("#myname").autocomplete({
                      source: 'emp.php',
                      select: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#myname").val(ui.item.label);
                        $("#myid").val(ui.item.id);
                    },
                       minLength: 0,
                       autoFocus: true,
                    }); 
                });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Ajax Testing</h2>
        <input  name="myname" id="myname" type="text">
        <input  name="myid" id="myid" type="text">
    </body>
</html>
-------------- Below is the code of PHP for emp.php page --------------------------
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
$query  = "SELECT myname as label , myid as id  FROM emp WHERE name LIKE ? ORDER BY name";
$rsTable = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query,array('%'.$_REQUEST['term'].'%'));
while ($row_rsTable = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rsTable, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $emparray[] = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $row_rsTable);
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes